# Angular ng-change vs ng-model performance

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs

Is there any performance improvement in using ng-change in an input instead of ng-model?

I pressume that when ng-model is used in an input, then a "$watch" (or similar) is made by angular in a variable, and that adds work load.

But if ng-change is used, then the variable (model) can be updated when needed, code can be executed only when this variable is changed by the input.

This works assuming that only one input can change a variable.

Example follows:

### using ng-model

```
<input type="text" ng-model="ElTexto">
<div ng-show="ElTexto"></div>
```

### using ng-change

html

```
<input type="text" ng-change="elTexto()">
<div ng-show="ElTexto"></div>
```

js

```
$scope.elTexto(){
  $scope.ElTexto = true;
}
```

Comment: I think `ng-change` better in performance. AngularJS don't needs to observe the `model` and simply wait a key triggering on the input.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`ng-change` *requires* `ng-model`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange), so you can't choose between the two.  You must use `ng-model`, and can also use `ng-change` if you wish.

Be aware that the two are VERY different.  `ng-model` will keep your input's value and its backing model in perfect sync; `ng-change` will indicate that the user is interacting with the input.  If you care about the value they're changing, like if you're doing autocomplete, just use `ng-model` and have all your code share the same variable.  If you specifically want to take an action when the input changes, regardless of what the value is, then you can use `ng-change` for that.

Comment: So in terms of performace, I cannot win or lose anything, because of the ng-model requirement. I'd downvote my question if I could. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`ng-change` will have batter performance then `ng-model`. As in every digest cycle `ng-model` will be evaluated while `ng-change` will be evaluated on change of input.